# Using Optional Binding and managing scope in Swift

Tags: swift

Can we not use optional binding on previously declared variables? It seems such a natural thing to be able to do now that there is `if let` and `guard`. I'm thinking something in the lines of:

```
var jsonData:AnyObject?

if jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) {
    //use jsonData! safely
}
//still be able to use jsonData?
```

Or

```
var jsonData:AnyObject?

guard jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) else {
    print("Could not parse JSON")
}
//still use jsonData?
```

Why the scope limitations? Why not keep it open for us to use the variables wherever?

What I am trying to do is avoid two separate statements when assigning/unwrapping an optional (and executing conditional code) which is what seemed to be the original purpose of `if let` and `guard` to begin with:

```
var jsonData: AnyObject?

jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
if(jsonData != nil) {
    //use jsonData! safely
}
//still use jsonData?
```

Is there a cool way to go about this or is the only option to use two statements?

**EDIT**

Looking over the code again, I see that my main use of this scenario is when trying to `print()` messages when assigning/unwrapping certain important optional variables **without major redirections of the flow**. The key statements from my *actual* code here are:

```
jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
if(jsonData == nil) {
    print("Could not parse data")
}
```

I was under the impression that `if let` and `guard` were made exactly for merging those two statements but I'm getting the feeling that that's not really what they were intended for. I hope I posted a more clearer explanation of my question in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127600/can-optional-binding-in-swift-help-here).

Comment: Do you need to use `jsonData` if it's `nil`?  What are you doing with it in the following lines in the case that it was `nil`?  To me, the answer to that largely impacts the best way to deal with your situation.

Comment: @nhgrif What happens later is that I then check if the HTML status code is successful or not and I have to handle the 4 combinations of successful-unsuccessful status code with nil-NOTnil jsonData. It means I have to check for `nil` later on anyway but I'm trying to reduce all these conditional if statements.

Comment: Can you post the actual code?  Or, if you actually have the concrete implementation and it's working as expected, but you want to know maybe a cleaner, more concise way of implementing it, perhaps check out [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  It will hard for me to give you much advice without actually seeing your current implementation.

Comment: @nhgrif I did not know about Code Review thanks. I've added a hopefully more detailed and clearer [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127600/i-want-to-run-some-conditional-code-based-on-a-regular-assignment-can-optional) there. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It's `guard let`, `guard` without `let` evaluates only a boolean expression

```
guard let jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) else {
    print("Could not parse JSON")
}
// use jsonData
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// use jsonData! safely
```

You should never use `!` in this case. The whole point of `if let` is to avoid the dangers of `!`. But to your question, the best way to do this IMO is:

```
let jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
if let jsonData = jsonData {
    // use jsonData as itself
}

// use jsonData? as optional
```

That said, I have very rarely encountered this kind of situation, and it may indicate poorly factored code. In any case, it's unclear that removing one line here would be worth further complicating the language, but if you have a compelling use case for changing Swift in this way, that's what the [Swift-Evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution) process is for.

Comment: If `jsonData != nil` succeeds, how could `jsonData!` in the `if` scope ever be unsafe?

Comment: If `jsonData` is scoped locally, it might be pretty difficult, but why introduce the crash operator that maintainers are going to spend time double, triple, quadruple checking when it's simple enough to just use the safe-unwrapping options that we're already using anyway.

Comment: There is a difference between "does not crash given the current code" and "safe." NULL-able pointers are totally "safe" as long as you correctly check them before use. Yet they are the largest cause of crashes in programming history. `!` is "safe" in exactly the same way. Swift introduced optionals precisely to avoid this problem; `!` is an escape valve for corner cases, not a normal way to access an optional.

Comment: Right, so @vadian if in some future refactor, the `jsonData != nil` is refactored out but the `jsonData!` remains, now the code is less safe, and there's not an obvious warning against this problem.  It may not be caught until well after the code is in the wild.  If you tried refactoring a `guard let` out but continued to reference the variable declared, your code would now no longer compile because you're using an undeclared variable.

Comment: @RobNapier I've noticed that I face this question mainly in situations where all I need to do is give a simple feedback to the user/programmer after an important assignment although it could be valid for things like logging as well and I'm sure other situations where you don't want to change the flow of the code too much. I just thought that `if let` and `guard` were mainly for that: merging assignment statements with conditional code and they seemed like a nice fit here but I see that that's not necessarily how they were intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it works the way you want it to.  Try the following in a playground to see the results.  The `myData` names as used in the `print` statements behave as different variables with different scopes.

```
func indefinite() throws -> AnyObject? {
    return "asd"
    //return nil
}

var myData: AnyObject?

if let myData = try indefinite() {
    print("Unwrapped \(myData.dynamicType)")
} else {
    print("Optional \(myData.dynamicType)")
}
```

If I was writing real code, I'd probably use...

```
if let safeData = try indefinite() {
    print("Unwrapped \(safeData.dynamicType)")
```

...instead.

Comment: Yes, and because they behave as different variables (and I think they ARE different - I believe you have two different variables called myData now, not just one) it's not really what I can use since I would still want to use the assigned value of myData after the `if let` scope. Sorry if my original purpose was not clear but thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not just do whatever work needs the assigned value **within** the scope?  That's basically the definition of `if let`: a scope where the unwrapping produced a non-nil value.

Comment: It's possible but in this particular case (and I don't think it's uncommon) restricting that code within the scope would be counter-intuitive to the logical flow. I have created a question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127600/i-want-to-run-some-conditional-code-based-on-a-regular-assignment-can-optional) if you are interested to see what I mean. The question has more code and I took more time to mull over what my issue was. If you have any suggestions for a better structure I would love to hear them.